# Matlab: Change plot axis to get the [0,0] point in the middle of the plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot some 2D lines with Matlab. I am trying to get the plot to show the intersection point between the x-axis and y-axis in the middle of the plot so I can see how the lines proceed in the negative x-range and y-range.

I've tried the `axis` command. But this will just scale the `XMIN XMAX YMIN YMAX`... etc in the `plot`

[image]

Thanks!

here is my code for plotting:

```
plot(AOA,y,'g-o')
hold on 
pl = plot(AOA,CLspanloading,'c-o');
 set(pl,'linewidth',2);
xlabel('Alpha')
ylabel('CL')
title('Lift Polar')
axis([-5 8 -1 1.5])
% legend('LowerCL','UpperCL','-Spanloading','Location','SouthEast')
legend('F27 Paper','Spanloading','Location','SouthEast')
```

Comment: Why not `axis([-8 8 -1.5 1.5])`?

Comment: Yes this Is that I did wrong. Thanks for the tip. these inputs actually work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `axis` command must be used wisely. The `XMIN` and the `XMAX` should have the same value and the same goes for `YMIN` ad `YMAX`. The only thing that must be changed, is the sign: indeed, `XMIN=-XMAX` and `YMIN=-YMAX` (where, of course `XMAX>0` and `YMAX>0`).

By running this simple code

```
plot(1:50,1:50,'g-o')
xlabel('Alpha')
ylabel('CL')
title('Lift Polar')
axis([-8 8 -8 8]); grid on;
```

i get

[image]

Now, sure this line doesn't mean a thing...it's just for demo purposes. But as you can see the origin is exactly in the middle of the plot.

Comment: If you want X from -5 to 7 and Y from 1.5 to -0.5 you'll never get the origin in the middle since your X-axis and Y-axis are not symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `xlim` and `ylim` to adjust the scale of the current axes:

```
xlim([XMIN XMAX]);
ylim([YMIN YMAX]);
```

And to center the axis on the origin in the plot, make sure the magnitudes of XMIN/XMAX are the same, as well as the magnitudes of YMIN/YMAX:

```
xlim([-XMAX XMAX]);
ylim([-YMAX YMAX]);
```